# Ansible: Make sure variable is a list

Tags: ansible

I am using the `community.general.filetree` module to list all files and directories within a config folder.

`community.general.filetree` however returns a list of dictionaries if there is at least two entries within that folder. If there is just a single file, it does not return a list with one entry, it returns the dictionary directly.

Is there a way to convert the returned value to a list *if its not already one*?

For reference, the task is

```yaml
- name: Compose - Configs - Fetch files in config folder
  set_fact:
    compose_create_directories: >-
      {{ compose_create_directories + [{"project": item, "directories": lookup('community.general.filetree', compose_config_folder)}] }}
  vars:
    compose_create_directories: []
  loop: "{{ compose_projects }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `lookup` with `query` which always returns a list.

See:

- [forcing lookups to return lists](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#forcing-lookups-to-return-lists-query-and-wantlist-true)
- [Loop documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#ensuring-list-input-for-loop-using-query-rather-than-lookup)

```yaml
query('community.general.filetree', compose_config_folder)
```

Note in the first link above that `query` has a handy alias as `q` to write compact code:

```yaml
q('community.general.filetree', compose_config_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! The same is also documented here (that's were I found it): https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#ensuring-list-input-for-loop-using-query-rather-than-lookup